# ERROR with bootstrap dependence having an unclosed block

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack, bootstrap-4, package-lock.json

I'm trying to compile a work repository on my personal computer (so I can work remotely), but every time I run `npm start` I get these messages:

```
npm ERR! Cannot read property 'match' of undefined

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/thiago/.npm/_logs/2019-12-14T14_08_32_310Z-debug.log
```

Well, following tons of websites I did (countless times) `rm -rf package-lock.json /node_modules`

After that, I can follow with the installation of the modules and it generates a new `package-lock.json`

Then, when I run `npm start` I get the following error:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--2-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib??ref--2-2!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--2-3!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--2-4!./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css
Module build failed: Syntax Error 

(4664:2) Unclosed block

  4662 | 
  4663 | .navbar-light .navbar-toggler-icon {
> 4664 |   background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='30' height='30' viewBox='0 0 30 30'%3e%3cpath stroke='rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-miterlimit='10' stroke-width='2' d='M4 7h22M4 15h22M4 23h22'/%3e%3c/svg%3e");
       |  ^
  4665 | }
  4666 | 

 @ ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css 4:14-221 18:2-22:4 19:20-227
 @ ./src/index.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:3000 webpack/hot/dev-server babel-polyfill react-hot-loader/patch webpack-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:3000 webpack/hot/only-dev-server whatwg-fetch ./src/index
Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":
     1 asset
    [./node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./index.hbs] ./node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./index.hbs 716 bytes {0} [built]
    [./node_modules/lodash/lodash.js] ./node_modules/lodash/lodash.js 541 kB {0} [built]
    [./node_modules/webpack/buildin/global.js] (webpack)/buildin/global.js 509 bytes {0} [built]
    [./node_modules/webpack/buildin/module.js] (webpack)/buildin/module.js 517 bytes {0} [built]
webpack: Failed to compile.
```

I tried to search a lot about it! But unfortunately, I don't get any clue. It's a webpack problem? Or bootstrap? Post-CSS? Or even none of those?
Thank you very much for your attention.
I much appreciate any help.

**EDIT**: A friend helped me and I decide to delete the class that caused the error
Another error appears:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--2-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib??ref--2-2!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--2-3!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--2-4!./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css
Module build failed: Syntax Error 

(4709:2) Unclosed block

  4707 | 
  4708 | .navbar-dark .navbar-toggler-icon {
> 4709 |   background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='30' height='30' viewBox='0 0 30 30'%3e%3cpath stroke='rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-miterlimit='10' stroke-width='2' d='M4 7h22M4 15h22M4 23h22'/%3e%3c/svg%3e");
       |  ^
  4710 | }
  4711 |
```

I also deleted this too and now it runs perfectly!

Well, if somebody knows why this happens and what is wrong, I very much appreciate it.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Solution is:

1. Remove all empty spaces.
2. Remove this block -> Compile -> Paste back and try Compile

Comment: Yeah, I removed the class blocks and it works. Thanks.